# Display epoch time as HHMM format in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, epoch

I have a variable that contains epoch time. I want to display the time in HHMM format.

Here is my code;

```
function epoch_time_to_date_obj(epoch_time)
{
    var utcSeconds = epoch_time;
    var d = new Date(0); 
    d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);    
    return d;
}

let epoch_time = 1234567890;
let date_obj = epoch_time_to_date_obj(epoch_time);
```

I would like to extract the HHMM time information from `date_obj` and display the time in HHMM format in Hong Kong time.

I am using node.js v6

Comment: The entire *epoch_time_to_date_obj* function can be replaced with `new Date(epoch_time * 1000)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let epoch_time = 1234567890 * 1000;
var date_obj = new Date(epoch_time);
const hrs = date_obj.getHours();
const mins = date_obj.getMinutes();
let hhmm = (hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs) + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins);

alert(hhmm);
```